# dart angular2 - two-ways binding in component

Tags: angular, dart

Is there a way to bind a field in a component as input and output ?

i.e.

```
<my-component [(innerComponentField)]="outerComponentField"></my-component>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `[]` the component needs a matching `@Input()`
For `()` it needs a matching `@Output()`.

There is no way to do both with just an `@Input()`

The combination `[(innerComponentFields)]` requires

```
@Input() dynamic innerComponentField;
@Output() EventEmitter innerComponentFieldChange = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have an example of code doing that? I didn't find a lot of information in the official documentation.

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs

Comment: Oups my bad. It works but I have to call myEventEmitter.emit() each time my value changes and I have to implement a method in my outer component to update my field. Thanks for your help.